# Pack vs bundle difference

Tags: word-choice

On digital stores, I have seen both **Pack** and **Bundle** to refer as a group of virtual items that are sold together.

I'd like to know which one is better for the given context

Example:

> There is a new bundle offered in the shop!
>
> There is a new pack offered in the shop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bundle of communications services: for instance, the Internet, cable TV and a telephone line.

Services are sold as a bundle. Software and software services (SaS, software as a service) can be sold bundled. The meaning is altogether. Bundle in this sense is a business idea or term, not a software idea.

Shops don't usually offer bundles, because as pointed out in the question, these are virtual items, when they are advertised the internet.

Pack is usually some kind of software update. The usual term is service pack. A service pack is a technical term, not a business term.

"A service pack (SP) is a collection of updates and fixes, called patches, for an operating system or a software program. Many of these patches are often released before a larger service pack, but the service pack allows for an easy, single installation."

That said, bundle and pack have non-virtual meanings which I am not addressing here.

[service pack](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-service-pack-2626010)

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what exactly you are offering. Bundle would be most common for a  variety of items. Set would imply some sort of relationship between items (e.g. Week 3 DLC set). Pack would imply that the items are inside a container of some kind, however, I've rarely seen pack used unless there was a real world equivalent (i.e. a digital card game advertising a "10 card pack").